# RenderPartial with model from _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

One of the overloads for `Html.RenderPartial` allows you to pass in a model.  How can you make use of that from `_Layout.cshtml`?

I have a model prepared with everything I need.  I just can't see how to make it accessible to the Layout.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("pMenu", menu); }
    </nav>
    ...
```

**pMenu.cshtml**

The partial view for the menu.  Hopefully this makes it clear that the menu is dynamic and really does need a model passed to it.

```
@model MyApplication.Menu

@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MyApplication.MenuGroup> group in Model.group)
{
    if (group.Key != "default")
    {
        <div>@group.Key.ToString()</div>
    }
    <ul>
        @foreach (MyApplication.MenuItem item in group.Value.items.Values)
        {
            <li>
                @if (item.isCurrent)
                {
                    <span class="@item.Icon">@item.LinkText</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.LinkText, item.Action, item.Controller, item.RouteValues, new { @class = @item.Icon })

                }
                @if (null != item.subItems)
                {
                    <ul class="tree">
                        @foreach (MyApplication.SubItem subitem in item.subItems)
                        {
                            <li>
                                @if (subitem.isCurrent)
                                {
                                    <span>@subitem.LinkText</span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @Html.ActionLink(subitem.LinkText, subitem.Action, subitem.Controller, subitem.RouteValues, null)
                                }
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

**Where is the menu instantiated?**

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        menu = new Menu(requestContext.RouteData.Values);
```

**Background information**

This is an intranet application.  It does not have the typical hard-coded menu options of "Home", "About", "Contact".  Most of the menu is created from user-maintained database records.  The menu is individualised to the user.  No two users will have the same menu items.  Eg: A manager gets a menu item for each of their staff.

The menu model also handles other factors that make the menu "dynamic" such as:

- identifying whether the requested page matches a given menu item (by route data) (for styling)
- adding extra menu items based on roles
- sometimes adding sub-menus for the current context

This seems similar to [#Render partial with a model in Layout View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722320/render-partial-with-a-model-in-layout-view) but I think that question went off the rails by referring to session.

Disclaimer: I'm an experienced programmer but relatively new to C# and asp.NET MVC.

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.Partial("pMenu", menu)`? Assuming `pMenu.cshtml` is in `~/Views/Shared/`

Comment: @Yvette I think my first go at asking that question was pretty confusing.  Hopefully it's a bit clearer after that edit.

Comment: @jrummell Either way, Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'menu' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Well then, you'll need to declare and instantiate that variable.

Comment: @jrummell I am instantiating menu on every page load via an extension of the Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewData to the rescue.

_Layout.cshtml

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("pMenu", ViewData["menu"]); }
```

MainController

```
menu = new Menu(requestContext.RouteData.Values);
ViewData["menu"] = menu;
```

Modifying `menu` after this point still works.  I'm not sure why, but I'll take it.

See also [Best way to do global viewdata in an area of my ASP.NET MVC site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198184/best-way-to-do-global-viewdata-in-an-area-of-my-asp-net-mvc-site)

Comment: See also: [Best way to do global viewdata in an area of my ASP.NET MVC site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198184/best-way-to-do-global-viewdata-in-an-area-of-my-asp-net-mvc-site)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to render a menu. from my view you should create a helper method for this purpose. If you want to go through this technique and if you are new to create your own tag then following this basic tutorial to get some undestanding : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and

Comment: EditorFor and DisplayFor templates are great.  I have made some and used them in other situations, but I don't think they're relevant here.  I have edited the question and added the partial view so hopefully that's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could always include a base index view that contains generic things then reference your layout in the page. You somewhat inherit the view and send in model data.

```
@model Model.MyIndexModel
@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_SinglePageLayout.cshtml";}
```

Comment: I don't follow.  Where would your code be placed and how would it be invoked?  Every page needs the menu plus whatever else is going on.